# R shiny How do I not run thw same function multiple times?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to:

(1) I take input from the user (In this toy model I take one piece of data (a constant to multiple a matrix). In the real world I take 10 inputs)

(2) I use that input to calculate a matrix (In this toy model it is just a random matrix multiple by the constant the user selected)

(3) I use the matrix from Step 2 to in multiple render plots (i.e. Plot #1 and Plot #2 use the same matrix from step 2. I want the calculations in Step 2 to be done ONLY ONCE.)

My problem is in Step #3. I do not know how to write the code so that the matrix in step #2 is calculated only once.

I am currently getting an error: 
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I attached the code to run the toy model and here is the code to kick it off. Just put it in a new script where "testShiny" is the name of the R project:

```
library(shiny)
runApp("C:/Users/me/Desktop/R Projects/testShiny")
```

here is the server.R file you can create:

```
 library(shiny)

 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

number<- reactive({ input$Number}) #get the input from the user


  testMatrix<- function()
  {
    number<- as.numeric(number())
     testMatrix<- replicate(10, rnorm(10)) *number #do some stuff with the input and return a matrix
  }

getMatrix<- reactive ({ testMatrix() }) #return the matrix to a matrix that can be used multiple     times and will recalulate when the user changes the  UI 

output$plotVector1 <- renderPlot({ 
    data[,1]<- testMatrix()
    plot(data) #plot the 1st column of the matrix
    })

output$plotVector2 <- renderPlot({ 
  data[,2]<- testMatrix()
  plot(data) #plot the 2nd column of the matrix
})

})
```

here is the ui.R file you can create:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarPanel(selectInput("Number", "Select Numbers", c(1,2,3,4), selected = 5)),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plotVector1"),
    plotOutput("plotVector2")   
             )
))
```

Let me know if this is not clear.  Thank you guys for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, above the plots do

```
eigenVectors<-reactive ({ eigenVectorsR() })
```

Then later when you need this, refer to it as `eigenVectors()`

**EDIT**

After looking at the newly updated question - the only thing you need to do is this:

replace:

```
data[,1]<- testMatrix()
plot(data)
```

with:

```
plot(testMtrix()[,1])
```

or whichever column you wish.

Your test application now works for me, hopefully you are good to go.

Comment: Sorry - forgot reactive in the original answer - edited to correct

Comment: When the input data changes, then the `eigenVectors()` will be "invalidated" meaning it will no longer correspond to the right data from the ui. At that point `eigenVectorsR()` should re-execute. Otherwise I should server both graphs - you should of course remove the `eigenVectors<-eigenVectorsR()` from the plot function and just use `eigenVectors()`.

Comment: So, have you tried doing `output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(eigenVectors[,4]*50, col= "red",type ="o", ylim=yLimit,  DateFrom, " to ", DateTo,sep=""), xlab="Month",lwd=2,ylab= "PC")})` ? The type of error you describe typically comes when you try to use something like a function as a list. If you do str(StaticE()) what do you get?

Comment: So that is a 18 X 18 matrix - which seems like it should work. If you just put in a string of random numbers (e.g. rnorm(18)) into the plot does it work? Could this error be coming from somewhere else in the code?

Comment: In the plot command you have above - there seems to be an error with labels one axis. after the `ylim=yLimit` you have  `DateFrom, " to ", DateTo,sep=""),`whihc looks like part of paste command and will generate an error - is this in your actual code or is it just a cut and paste error posting it here?

Comment: *********** I HAVE UPDATED THIS QUESTION WITH A TOY MODEL*********